# How to make a 'Kivy' ui persist when running an exe created using pyinstaller

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

Trying to create a simple exe file using pyinstaller that i can then distribute to other users. the python code uses kivy to create front end. However, when i run the exe (created using pyinstaller --onefile) the command window and the kivy window closes instantly. i want to make the ui persist until the user closes it.

i am using Python 3.7

Below is the simple kivy code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

When i run the exe via command prompt i get the below

```
[WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image <C:\Users\aa\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI280362\kivy_install\data\glsl\default.png>
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 140, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 968, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 294, in create_window
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1216, in create_window
  File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 759, in kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 536, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 732, in _set_filename
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 435, in load
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 201, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py", line 41, in load

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: It probably lacks some dll or pyinstaller configuration so run it from the CMD and you will surely see an error message that you should share with us.

Comment: thanks. edited the main post with the cmd error

Comment: When you run without converting it to .exe do not you have that same problem?

Comment: no. when i run the python kivy,py from command prompt, i do not get any errors and the code runs fine

Comment: see https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html

Comment: let me give this a try and get back.

Comment: I would say first try without --onefile, i've had good successes without it, and i think it's a common source of issues. (i usually then use an installer generator like innosetup to generate a full installer).

Comment: @eyllanesc followed your recommendation and tried editing the spec file and regernated the exe. unfortunately, same behavior. the kivy ui does not persist.

Comment: @Tshirtman let me give it a try and get back

Comment: ok so i managed to get to a point where i have one exe and a bunch of .dll files and the exe runs fine. however, if i delete the .dll files, the application crashes. Any ideas on how i can package the dll files within the same exe file? All i did to get until this point was to edit the .spec (added a collection object) and recreate the exe file